# Image is not being painted upon dragging mouse

Tags: java, image, swing, mouse

I am making some project which requires dragging objects on the screen. In my main class I have such listener

```
addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter(){
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e){
                currentX = e.getX() - 10 ;
                currentY = e.getY() - 5;

                if(currentNote != null)
                {

                    if(!editingMode)
                    {
                        graphics2D.setPaint(Color.BLACK);
                        currentNote.setParameters(currentX, currentY, NoteDrawing.SKIP_CHECK);
                        currentNote.paintComponent(graphics2D);

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        graphics2D.setPaint(Color.BLACK);
                        currentNote.setParameters(currentNote.getBallFromX(), currentY, NoteDrawing.SKIP_CHECK);
                        currentNote.paintComponent(graphics2D);
                    }

                }
                repaint();
            }
        })
```

Now in the object (extending JComponent) which should be painted I have the following paintComponent method:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(bmoll,fromX, fromY,null);
        g.drawLine(fromX, fromY, fromX + 30, fromY);
        repaint();

    }
```

and the setting parameters method:

```
public void setParameters(int x, int y) {
        this.fromX = x;
        this.fromY = y;

    }
```

When I press the button over the object and then drag the mouse, the line drawn in paintComponent method is dragged properly, the image however is not. The image is not null - it appears on the screen in its original position. If I duplicate the line `g.drawImage(bmoll,fromX, fromY,null);` with different coordinates it is being drawn in two places as it should. But when I drag the mouse - nothing happens with it. If anyone has some suggestions about what is causing the problem, I shall be grateful.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example). 2) One way to get image(s) for an example is to hot-link to the images seen in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19209651/418556). 3) You forgot to ask a question.  What is your question?

Comment: My question... I meant to ask what causes my problem. Now it is not relevant anymore, cause thanks to your suggestion about MCVE I found what the bug was while I was preparing the example to post. The problem was in one of the objects constructor. Thank you for your help!!

Comment: I choose to write an answer just in case anyone got similar problem - I'll be able to accept it in two days though.

Comment: *"I choose to write an answer just in case anyone got similar problem"* I was hoping you'd choose that option.  ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the problem was in the object's constructor. In the original object's creation the program calls for:

```
public Bmoll(int startX, int startY)
    {
        this.fromX = startX;
        this.fromY = startY;
        this.inverted = false;
        this.staff = Staff.getActiveStaff();
        this.bmoll = GuiHelper.getImage(B_MOLL_FILE);
    }
```

while, when creating the object for dragging, the empty constructor was called and thus the image object `bmoll` was null - there was nothing to be drawn.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you call `super.paintComponent`
2. Painting is done within the context of the paint methods, you should never need to call `paint` or `paintComponent` yourself
3. Use `paintComponent` to paint the current state
4. When clicked, prepare the state and call `repaint`
5. When dragged, update the state and call `repaint`